# Can not be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I did not change anything.

FullScreenActivity code:

```
 package com.example.button;

import com.example.button.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

activity_fullscreen.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="com.example.button.FullscreenActivity" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:text="Click me"
        android:layout_marginTop="211dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I only added the `. button` part. The error is:

```
fullscreen_content_controls cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Here:

```
 final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
```

What can be the reason? I did not change anything. Only added button. This is a simple applicati0n.

Comment: where do you have `fullscreen_content_controls` defined? In your XML I only see a `TextView` with the ID `fullscreen_content` and a `Button` with the ID `dummy_button`

Comment: I did not define it but when i define it in R. , it still gives errors.

Comment: How do you `define it in R`?

Comment: Near error, it suggests to define as field in R. public static int fullscreen_content_controls;

Comment: I asked `How`, not where. Please post an example. If you want do `define something for R`, you just have to add it to the layout. (For example: If you want to access the Button `dummy_button` you could use it like `R.id.dummy_button`, but something which is nowhere defined (like `fullscreen_content_controls`), you cannot access it, because it's not available.

Comment: is this the complete layout xml file? where is the fullscreen_content_controls view?

Comment: WHen i click suggestion for errors, it defines that in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you perhaps remove `</FrameLayout>` from activity_fullscreen.xml ?

EDIT:
Well you are finding views:

```
final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

The second one (fullscreen_content) exists in your layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
.../>
```

But the first one (fullscreen_content_controls) doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `fullscreen_content_controls` doesn't exist, what are trying to call there???

Comment: I only added button. Others appeared themselves.

Comment: you are trying to find `fullscreen_content_controls` which doesn't exist, and they cannot appear themselves, either you imported the code like that or you deleted the fullscreen_content_controls in layout

Comment: I just used graphical layout while inserting button. Can it delete?

Comment: no it cannot delete it like that, post the code without your editings